# Excel dynamic offset table with results criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, excel-formula, offset

I am looking for a way to make a dynamically updated table in excel using a linked data source with filtered results.

What I currently have is a form control scrollbar that is linked to a random cell. That random cell drives an offset function (below) to pull results from the linked data table in another worksheet. All of this works wonderful but I am looking to strip out rows that meet a certain criteria, which I already have calculating to a true/false result in the table itself to make it simple. What I cannot figure out is how to modify my current offset lookup to filter out the results that are false in my calculated column.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C2,$I$99,0,1,1)
```

Sheet1 is where the linked data table is located.

$I$99 is where the cell link for my scrollbar is.

As the scrollbar moves the value in the cell link changes thus updating the offset lookup down the table. I should also state there are 14 rows in my table as well. I will need to filter out the false results but also in turn omit the blank rows as there are over 400 rows in the source table and only about 30 true results in the calculated column.

I unfortunately cannot provide the workbook I am using as it has company sensitive data in it but if it is absolutely needed I can create a filler document with made up data to provide something to work with.

I have looked at advanced filters already and they will not do the trick as they are not dynamic in nature. I would like a non VBA solution as this is a dashboard project that I will be distributing to my team here at work and macros are disabled on our network for security reasons every time an excel is opened so it will become a nuisance.

Let me know if you all need anything else from me.

Comment: okay got halfway there, updated the offset formula to the following and now I get only the results I want but the table is full of blank spaces that I have no idea how to remove.

`=IF(LEFT(OFFSET(Sheet1!$K2,$I$99,0,1,1),1)="T",OFFSET(Sheet1!$C2,$I$99,0,1,1),"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a little help from a friend, coded each cell to function as an array part and it works like a charm.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Dashboard_Data[Summary],SMALL(IF(LEFT(Dashboard_Data[Stale],1)="T",IF(Dashboard_Data[Visible],ROW(Dashboard_Data[Visible])-1,""),""),ROW(A1)+$K$18)),"")}
```